# Break / exit from nested blocks in R without printing error messages

Tags: r, control-flow

I've been writing an R script that would simulate outbound phone calls from a call center to demonstrate the rules ( if the call counts exceeds 5 OR if the call is a success OR a call back request is set then the code should exit). If I use `break` statement, I'm not getting the desired result, as a workaround I'm using the `stop` function. Is there a way to print a message and stop executing a function without throwing an Error ?
This is my code:

```
dial <- function(callcount = 1)
{
  maxcalls <- 5
  # Possible Outcomes
  outcomes <- c("RPCON","WPCON","CBLTR")
  # Probaility Vector for results:
  pvector <- c(1,1,1)

  repeat{
    if(callcount == 5){
      stop("5 attempts reached, closing record for the day")
      }
    res <- sample(outcomes, 1, prob=pvector, rep = TRUE)
    print(paste0("Attempt ",callcount))
  if(res == "RPCON" & callcount <= 5){
    print("Call Successful")
    stop(simpleError("Ended"))
  }else if(res == "WPCON" & callcount <= 5){
    print("Wrong Party!, Trying alternate number...")
    callcount <- callcount + 1
    dial(callcount)
  }else if(res == "CBLTR" & callcount <= 5){
    print("Call back request set by agent")
    stop("Ended")
  }
}# End of REPEAT loop

}# End of function
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `stop` raises an error, `break` breaks out of a `for`, `while`, or `repeat` loop, and `return` ends function execution (and returns something, if you tell it to).

Comment: @alistaire If I use `break` instead of `stop`, it only comes out of the if block. If I use a `return` statement, the function continues until the callcount reaches 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a While loop with a boolean to check if you want to continue to loop :

```
dial <- function(callcount = 1)
{
  maxcalls <- 5
  # Possible Outcomes
  outcomes <- c("RPCON","WPCON","CBLTR")
  # Probaility Vector for results:
  pvector <- c(1,1,1)

  endLoop <- FALSE
  while(callcount <=5 & endLoop == FALSE ){
    if(callcount == 5){
      stop("5 attempts reached, closing record for the day")
    }
    res <- sample(outcomes, 1, prob=pvector, rep = TRUE)
    print(paste0("Attempt ",callcount))
    if(res == "RPCON" & callcount <= 5){
      print("Call Successful")
      endLoop <- TRUE
    }else if(res == "WPCON" & callcount <= 5){
      print("Wrong Party!, Trying alternate number...")
      callcount <- callcount + 1
      dial(callcount)
    }else if(res == "CBLTR" & callcount <= 5){
      print("Call back request set by agent")
      endLoop <- TRUE
    }
  }# End of REPEAT loop

}# End of function
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you @cyrilb38. I think the `if(callcount==5){...}` part can also be omitted.